# Xournal++ does not change the color of LaTex equation

Tags: latex, bugs, wacom, xournal

Xournal++ is a very sofisticated program for digital pen/table, but have a bug with colour of Latex equations. It is like in the imagem below. It doesn't matter you make, the color is the same. Look, the red colour even was not selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the definite solution, but you can change the manually it like in the image below. Select explictly the color

[image]